# ArcGis JS: Radius of circle created by Editor Toolbar

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

The Editor class has this option to show the toolbar (`toolbarVisible:true`). I want to modify the toolbar's "draw-end" event so I can control the radius of the circle.

The toolbar has a 'circle' option, but when you place the circle the radius appears to be arbitrary when I want it to be 10.

[image: example of toolbar]

Comment: Adding a screenshot of what you're referring to would be helpful.

Comment: @EmilBrundage Edited!

Comment: If I understand correctly, when drawing a circle, a polygon graphic is created by the tool. So you could potentially adjust the coordinates in the evt.geometry.rings arrays.